# Slow Bokeh Histogram

Tags: bokeh

I am trying to use the Bokeh Histogram in Jupyter but am finding it incredibly slow and I do not know why.

Here's what I'm doing. I generate 100 rows (initially way larger but have limited it to 100 for test purposes) that is read from SQLite and stored in 'res'

```
sqlStr ='Select SecsSincePrevPlay as MinsSinceFirstPlay from tblMain order by userID, historyID limit 100'
res = pd.read_sql_query(sqlStr, db)
```

I've checked that portion of it and it runs quick.

I then do:

```
p = Histogram(res, title="Seconds since previous play")
output_notebook()
show(p)
```

and this is the bit that is incredibly slow (to the point I've always had to abandon running it).

Interestingly when I load an extremely small dataset into my sqlLite database, the code seems to work - although its takes 20+ seconds even then when I'd expect it to be very quick. In this scenario the actual number of rows returns by res is still 100, it's just the database that contains less rows. I've checked the memory  usage and that doesn't appear to be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out through trial and error.

If your input data contains any very large outliers, it will slow down the rendering considerably UNLESS you also specify the bins.

In my case most of the data was in the 0-500 range but I had one that was 152007. This caused it to slow down considerably. Setting the bins to 25 brought it back to it's zippy self.

I may post this in some other groups that I visited in the hunt for the answer as didn't see it mentioned.